# Can you aggregate a bunch of Mongoid sets into a bulk transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Mongoid provides the no-callback method .set:

```
m = Model.where(..
m.set(something: true)
```

This method ONLY updates the something field, and leaves all other attributes intact.

Is there an analog to bulk update for .set, where you can gang them together into one bulk transaction?  I'm looking for something like:

```
Model.bulk do
   Model.all.each do |m|
       m.set(something: value)
```

Is this possible?  The intent is to reduce load on the db by doing batch updates, what I'm looking for is if this is possible with native Mongoid methods.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a session using `with_session` as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-sessions/).
2. Use `with_transaction` on the session object as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-transactions/#using-transactions).
3. Inside the `with_transaction` block perform the desired `set`s.